# How to pass specific colum name for excluding to modify in update method of generic data access layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have generic data access layer with this code:

```
  public abstract class GenericDataRepository<T, C> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
{
    private C _entities = new C();
    public C Context
    {
        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual void Update(Func<T, bool> excludeColumns, params T[] items)
    {

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            _entities.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        }

        _entities.SaveChanges();

    }


}
```

In this call, I have the update method that takes 2 params. 2nd is for domain model and 1st for list of columns in domain model that I don't want to update while  updating records, the solution is very pretty straight bu using this  sample method

```
db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.desireColumnName).IsModified = false;
```

but my problem is I want to pass that column name in param that's why the first param of update method comes in action. 
I just want to ask that this is the correct structure for solving my problem

```
Func<T, bool> excludeColumns
```

and second thing how I can pass my desire column name from drive calls, I mean I don't know the code.

this is my drive class code from where I want to pass the param

```
public void UpdateCountries(String userID, params Country[] records)
    {
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            record.UserIdEdit = userID;
            record.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        };
        var db =_countryRepository.getDb();

        _countryRepository.Update(records);
    }
```

i have a dbcontext here by  this code

```
var db =_countryRepository.getDb();
```

so, for example, I want to exclude my field CreatedDate of Country model, how I can pass this param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
public virtual void Update<P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> excludeColumn, params T[] items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        _entities.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;                
        _entities.Entry(item).Property(excludeColumn).IsModified = false;
    }
    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
repo.Update(x => x.CreatedDate, records);
```